# Elasticsearch treats strings as date

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm trying to use elasticsearch in pair with logstash and use it for storing my exim logs.

Particularly, I would like to extract message id field from log files to simplify searching on it:

```
  grok {
    match => [
        "@message", "%{DATE} %{TIME} %{HOSTNAME:msgid} %{GREEDYDATA:details}"
    ]
  }
  mutate {
    gsub => [
        "msgid","[\\\:-]",""
    ]
  }
```

As elasticsearch tries to parse as Date every string, that contains symbols like : / or -, I'm replacing them with mutate filter.

Unfortunately, even filtered msg id is not accepted by elasticsearch and the question is why?

```
    [2013-12-24 21:32:32,823][DEBUG][action.bulk              ] [Piledriver] 
    [logstash 2013.12.24][0] failed to execute bulk item (index) index 
    {[logstash-2013.12.24][exim][_7-j53yZRzmARuYsJEfgIA], 
    source[{"message":"<22>Dec 24 21:32:31 host exim[15691]: 
          2013-12-24 21:32:31 1VvWmN-000453-Fz Completed",
          "@version":"1",
          "@timestamp":"2013-12-24T21:32:31.000+03:00",
          "type":"exim",
          "host":"192.168.169.228",
          "syslog_pri":"22",
          "syslog_program":"exim",
          "syslog_pid":"15691",
          "received_at":"2013-12-24 18:32:31 UTC",
          "received_from":"192.168.169.228",
          "syslog_severity_code":6,
          "syslog_facility_code":2,
          "syslog_facility":"mail",
          "syslog_severity":"informational",
          "@source_host":"host",
          "@message":"2013-12-24 21:32:31 1VvWmN-000453-Fz Completed",
          "msgid":"1VvWmN000453Fz"}]}
    org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: failed to parse [msgid]
        at   org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.AbstractFieldMapper.parse(AbstractFieldMapper.java:401)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.serializeValue(ObjectMapper.java:613)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.parse(ObjectMapper.java:466)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:516)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:460)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard.prepareCreate(InternalIndexShard.java:353)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.shardIndexOperation(TransportShardBulkAction.java:402)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportShardBulkAction.java:156)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction.performOnPrimary(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:556)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction$1.run(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:426)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: failed to parse date field [1VvWmN000453Fz], tried both date format [dateOptionalTime], and timestamp number with locale []
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.DateFieldMapper.parseStringValue(DateFieldMapper.java:487)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.DateFieldMapper.innerParseCreateField(DateFieldMapper.java:424)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.NumberFieldMapper.parseCreateField(NumberFieldMapper.java:194)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.AbstractFieldMapper.parse(AbstractFieldMapper.java:390)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "1VvWmN000453Fz" is malformed at "VvWmN000453Fz"
        at org.elasticsearch.common.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseMillis(DateTimeFormatter.java:754)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.DateFieldMapper.parseStringValue(DateFieldMapper.java:481)
        ... 15 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Please share your elasticsearch Mapping if you have applied it on your index.
If not then share the default mapping that is getting created once you create the index.

Also you could try giving default mapping as String to msgid